# How to configure Tomcat for virtual hosting?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat

Hey I want to access my application only through host name .. can you please tell how and where to configure it into tomcat

```
e.g http://host-name : 8080/myapp 
I want only http:// host-name
```

Comment: did you mean you want to access your application from another computer.

Comment: please refer to http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html

Answer (score 0):

Rename your war deployed in tomcat server as root.war and you can access your application by
hitting the url below:

```
http://host-name : 8080/
```

Answer (score 0):

About the port, run Tomcat on 80 instead of 8080. Refer to [this](http://java-notes.com/)